# postgres database connection issue with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, postgresql

I am facing problem while connecting my eclipse with postgres db.It is giving this error while connecting to the database:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **FATAL: password authentication failed for user "abhi"**  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:67)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:216)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274)    at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
>     at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

**

[eclipse connection problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UCh9.png)

[eclipse connection problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOmiL.png)

I am using the correct database name and the correct user id and password.

When I go to the postgres application using pgadmin3 there I am able to connect with the same password

Any idea what's wrong here?

[image]
[image]